# PGP Encryption in Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, pgp

I'm looking to do some client-side PGP encryption in Javascript. I've found some GPL library scattered on the web, but for obvious reason, I cannot use that code due to licensing issues.

I'm looking for some BSD-like license library that would accomplish the same thing. Anyone know of a library I could use?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recently found a MIT licensed client-side javascript library:

https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl

It works well so far, and it allows for a full-client side encryption of the data. Ensuring that even before the data leaves the browser, it is already safe using a public-private key encryption scheme.

Comment: Nope. The Stanford Lib does not do PGP, but it still does public/private encryption scheme which is good enough for my needs.

Answer (score 19):

[OpenPGP.js](http://openpgpjs.org/) is probably the most complete and fastest implementation (it's a collaborative effort) and licensed under the LGPL.
You might want to join their mailing list.

Comment: Really nice! I will consider it for future projet :)

Answer (score 6):

See http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/

Comment: did you notice the same link in the one year old comment in the other answer ?

Comment: The library is GPL license. (or at least a dependency is GPL license) and cannot be used in a commercial application. Sorry but no cigar.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I recently found: https://keybase.io/kbpgp when looking for a similar item.  BSD Licensed instead of *GPL.

Comment: This seems to be the best implementation so far